# Send confirmation email after google form completion so user can see update response

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have set up a form in order to collect data that consists of various user information.  I have enabled the user to be able to update their submission.  The problem with this is that once a user leaves the final screen after submitting the form - there is no way to get back to that particular entry in order to update it.

As an example - A user may have made 5 entries over a time period and then something changes and they need to go back and update data for the first entry.  With the current system - there is no way for them to go back to a particular entry.

From what I can tell in searching the internet there use to be an option for a confirmation email to be sent after completing the form and that had a link to the entry.

Apparently Google has done away with this feature.

I did find some work around for sending out confirmation emails but I am not sure if they will allow the user to go back to a particular entry.

So in summary - in case the above may be confusing:

1 - is there a way for the completer of the form to go back to the form and select a particular submission in order to update it?

2 - if there isn't a way to select a particular entry - can a confirmation email  be sent to the user that lists their responses and contains a link back to that particular entry so that it can be updated (I understand that they will have to maintain the confirmation email in order to update the specific entry but that would be fine).

In regards to the confirmation email - Is there a way to list the responses that they submitted - and if they go in and update it I would expect that another email would fire with the updates.

I did see part of a solution from the below post from Paul - but I know nothing about programming so don't know how to incorporate this into a script of some sort.

[How to add "Edit Response" link to Google Forms emails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710354/how-to-add-edit-response-link-to-google-forms-emails)

Please let me know if this is something you can help me with.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can send [confirmations with Google Scripts](http://www.labnol.org/internet/auto-confirmation-emails/28386/) but these won't have links for the user to edit their responses. As a workaround, at the time of creating the form, you can turn on the option that will offer the user a link to edit their most recently submitted response.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have a editable link within confirmation email after submit.

If you are familiar with Google Apps script check the following link 
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getEditResponseUrl()