# How to load edit form url in custom google confirmation page

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a google form on my webpage (custom css linking to Google spreadsheet on submit). 
Once a user presses submit a custom confirmation page appears.

How do I load a link via html for the user to edit their response using Google's [getEditResponseUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getEditResponseUrl())?

I have read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710354/how-to-add-edit-response-link-to-google-forms-emails) and ben's post seems to have the answer, however I don't know how to link a button or hyperlink from this script.