# Make rows of a Google spreadsheet editable in a Google form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm looking for a way to edit a large Google spreadsheet collectively via a form for each row in the spreadsheet. (I don't want to simply give access to the spreadsheet to everyone because some fields have multiple lines and are a bit hard to edit directly inside of the spreadsheet.)

I've managed to create pre-filled forms for each row with [Is it possible to 'prefill' a google form using data from a google spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108511/is-it-possible-to-prefill-a-google-form-using-data-from-a-google-spreadsheet?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [How to prefill Google form checkboxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393556/how-to-prefill-google-form-checkboxes). (and I then can create a view as an Awesome-table with a button for each row which opens the pre-filled form corresponding to the row).

But the responses do not update the existing rows but add a new row (at row 2 strangely enough, protecting the headers, but messing up the Awesome-table that needs filter information in row 2).

How can I make a pre-filled form that writes at a specific row of a sheet? If possible the same row that the pre-fill was created from. Maybe with some script that is triggered by the submission of the form and which replaces the standard recording? Or is there a completely other way to edit Google spreadsheets by means of forms?

---

**Update:**

This was much harder than expected and I finally got back to it. Here is what I ended up hacking together:
A spreadsheet document document with three sheets:

- *main*: The main data
- *temp*: only used for the automatically added entries after submission
- *links*: keeping the editing links and response ids corresponding to each line of the main sheet

Then

- A function that can be triggered from the menus: creates a prefilled answer per line of *main*, submits, and puts the url and id in the *links* sheet. These links are distributed to different people who are asked to update the prefilled information of their row by means of the form.
- A onFormSubmit function attached to the form that

  - searches for the line with the right response id in *links*
  - updates the corresponding line in *main*

So the *temp* sheet is not used at all, all entries are handled manually. What I haven't managed to do is to allow a manual change in the main table and to resubmit the data under the same id. (I don't want to make a completely new response because the links are already distributed.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I edit the response of a form submission in Google Forms/Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37768819/how-do-i-edit-the-response-of-a-form-submission-in-google-forms-sheets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pre-filled URL allways will create a new form response. Instead you should use the URL returned by [getEditResponseUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#geteditresponseurl). For details see this other question

[How do I edit the response of a form submission in Google Forms/Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37768819/1595451)