# Make a new response from an existing Google Form response

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have studied this question and found it helpful:
[How do I edit the response of a form submission in Google Forms/Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37768819/how-do-i-edit-the-response-of-a-form-submission-in-google-forms-sheets)

Now I would like to take it a step further. Once I have the editable response URL, I notice that when I go to the URL and edit and submit the response, it modifies the original response line in the sheet.

What if, instead of modifying, I want to make a NEW response. That is, upon editing, when I Submit, the set of responses makes a NEW row in the spreadsheet. I'm trying to think of a way I can do this, but not coming up with anything. Any ideas?

Comment: What does your code look like that doesn't work? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.